# When is Layer.build() invoked in source code in keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, keras-layer, keras-2

Every derived class of Layer class in keras has `build()` definition.

`build()` is place where we assign weights to the keras layer.

When is this function invoked internally? I am unable to find any piece of code which may be callling it

In `__call_()` of Layer class at [topology.py:580](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/b187ac51e0c9ae6fab4aabfb12ceed57c83b12ba/keras/engine/topology.py#L580), we call `self.build()` but it will be invoked only when `self.built = True`. That is always set in `self.build()` which in turn will be invoked only when self.built is True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed `not` in the condition ([source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/b187ac51e0c9ae6fab4aabfb12ceed57c83b12ba/keras/engine/topology.py#L560)):

```py
if not self.built:
  ...
  if len(input_shapes) == 1:
    self.build(input_shapes[0])
  else:
    self.build(input_shapes)
```

... which basically means "build if not already".

By the way, `build()` is also called in `count_params()` method, again with a guard ([source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/b187ac51e0c9ae6fab4aabfb12ceed57c83b12ba/keras/engine/topology.py#L1269)).